# c# groupBy failing with key not found exception

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I retrieve BsonDocuments using the mongoDb driver in C#.

After this, I have a grouping method used to regroup my documents with a given Key.
Here is an example of objects returned from mongo :

```
{{ "_id" : ObjectId("57762d37de7d9c1cbc53bc10"), "DraftNumber" : "227232AA", "EndDate" : ISODate("2016-09-29T08:45:14.986Z"), "ProjectNumber" : "17E618BB" }}
```

Here is the beginning of my method used to regroup :

```
internal List<Project> RegroupProject(IEnumerable<BsonDocument> projects)
{
    var regroupProjectList = new List<Project>();

    var groupedProject = projects.GroupBy(project => project["ProjectNumber"]).ToList();
    [...]
}
```

And I got the following exception en `groupBy` expression :

> Element 'ProjectNumber' not found.

What do you think about that ? 
Is it because one of my 18k element has no value for `ProjectNumber` field ?

Comment: I would think you guessed the right reason. How about filtering those ones out before grouping? For example: `projects.Where(p => p.Contains("ProjectNumber")).GroupBy(project => project["ProjectNumber"]).ToList();`?

Comment: The other theory is because there is a double `{` instead of one. I don't understand why

Comment: Well give my suggestion a go, or you could try the other overload to specify a default which may be more appropriate: `project["ProjectNumber", "DefaultValue"]`

Comment: Your first suggestion is completly right :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have guessed correctly that one or more of the 18k items doesn't have a `ProjectNumber` property. There's a couple of options that I can see.

1. Filter out the items that don't have the property:

   ```
   var groupedProject = projects
       .Where(p => p.Contains("ProjectNumber"))
       .GroupBy(project => project["ProjectNumber"])
       .ToList();
   ```
2. Specify a default value for items missing the value:

   ```
   var groupedProject = projects
       .GroupBy(project => project["ProjectNumber", "<DefaultValue>"])
       .ToList();
   ```